# How can I Open Facebook from other app which is Installed & logged in Facebook App

Tags: ios, facebook

I have seen an iPhone app Path and Installed in Device and in this app I have seen Facebook functionality means **I have installed Facebook App and successfully logged in this app** and now **How can I open  my profile,feeds,friend list and other functionality from my demo app** so please give me idea how can I develop this functionality.

Comment: Here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021729/how-to-relaunch-an-app-like-facebook-ios-sdk-does you can find similar post.

Answer (score 1):

Any application can register a custom URL scheme, and when your app opens that URL, IOS will switch to the application that has registered that URL scheme. The Facebook app has registered such a scheme, with apparently quite some capabilities. See [wiki.akosma.com](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook).

However, I don't think that you can switch back to your app after that. So, if you just want to fetch some Facebook information, then you are probably better off using the [Facebook web interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform). You don't need to have the Facebook app installed at all when doing that.